# Powering RaspberryPi 4B and 2 2.5' HDDs via Header

Tags: pi-4

I'm new to this forum. I'm a programmer and have basic knowledge of electronics.
I'm interested in deploying my own self-hosted solutions. I'm eager to deploy my own NAS and other services like Pi-Hole or VPN (OpenVPN or WireGuard) server.
It'll be my first approach to RaspberryPi. I've watched some setup tutorials and read some forums, and what I've learned is that the optimal option for me will be to use RAID 0 on 2 disks (HDD 2.5'). But AFAIK RaspberryPi 4 will not manage to power those two disks via USB, so an external power supply will be needed. I'm thinking if it's possible to buy a header that will take one charger and will be able to power both raspberry and the disks (or disk controller). Is there such an option? Is y approach good or you think it should be corrected?